# How to transfer arrayList elements into a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayLists` called `List<Pair> patternList = new ArrayList<>()` that contains a number of patterns of length 2.  for example, for A={1,2,3,4} I create some patterns like (1,3)(3,2)...etc. I want to put these patterns into a 2d array(matrix)[A][A] in way that the patterns must go into a specific index in the matrix, For instance pattern (1,3) must go into index [3][3] or pattern (3,2) must go in [2][2].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to put them in by the second index. (edited to allow multiple per index):

```
List<Pair>[][] matrix = new LinkedList<Pair>[5][5]; //Replace 5 here a getter for the maximum value of A
                                  //Here it's 5 because the max of your example is 4.
//Initialize all positions of matrix to empty list.
for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++){
    for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++){
        matrix[r][c] = new LinkedList<Pair>();
    }
}
for (Pair p : patternList){
    if (matrix[p.second][p.second] == null)
        matrix[p.second][p.second] = new LinkedList<Pair>();
    matrix[p.second][p.second].add(p);
}
```

This isn't really using the 2d aspect of the array though; you could accomplish exactly the same thing with a 1d array of lists:

```
List<Pair>[] arr = new LinkedList<Pair>[5]; //Replace 5 here a getter for the maximum value of A
                                  //Here it's 5 because the max of your example is 4.
//Initialize all positions of array to empty list.
for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++){
    arr[r] = new LinkedList<Pair>();
}
for (Pair p : patternList){
    if (arr[p.second] == null)
        arr[p.second] = new LinkedList<Pair>();
    arr[p.second].add(p);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to put both (1,3) and (2,3) into [3][3], is it possible to put more than 1 item into one index? and that's going on for all the other patterns

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add that, but realize at that point you're not making use of the 2-d aspect of the array, because you're only ever using the indices on the diagonal. Perhaps you want a 1-d array with lists on indices?

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I want to use , I want the diagonal part but afterwards I will use the patterns once again and I will put more things in the array

Comment: ah. Ok, so use the first code block. The diagonal elements will be lists that can have as many elements as you want in them.

Comment: The problem with the above is that you need to create an empty list for each position of the array. As written `matrix[p.second][p.second].add(p);` will result in NullPointerException.

Comment: hence the list construction in the if block right above that?

Comment: +1 Doh. Sorry, for some reason didn't see it. This is where a `Multimap` is nice.

Comment: I agree, but the asker wants the indices and the rest of the square matrix for later.

Comment: Square is relative. If the only keys used fall into a `square` range great. I would create an unsquare array but only use the square portion. As long as the key is a List of two integers whose values never exceed some limit, you have a square. Obviously this is not enforces like it is in an array, but you don't have to worry about forgetting to create the list. Also, what should the array return if accessed on a location that hasn't been initialized. Empty lists are preferable to null.

Comment: Just initialize every index to an empty array. I'll add that to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep more than one element at each position, I suggest you use a `Multimap`. A `Multimap` is basically a `Map<Key, Collection<Value>>` that takes care of creating the collections for you.

[Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

```
 Multimap<List<Integer>, Pair> myMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

 for (Pair p : myPairs){
     List<Integer> key = Lists.newArrayList(p.second, p.second);
     myPair.put(key, p);
 }
```

Comment: Java does not know what is Multimap I think I have to create a different class for it, and I think the last line of your code you mean `myMap.put(key, p);`. Actually I tried `HashMap` before but the algorithm that I implement says Create a Matrix[A][A] and put the pattern list in it.

Comment: See my link. Multimap is a class provided in the Guava library. If you don't know how to use libraries yet, stick with Mshnik's answer.